# What is the meaning of a fiber cutoff wavelength when given as a range?

Tags: experimental-physics, laser, fiber-optics, birefringence

Many polarization maintaining fibers (for example Corning PM 1550) have a cutoff wavelength specified as a range (for example 1300-1440nm). What is the meaning of this range from the physics point of view and why isn't it a single value like that given for most SM fibers?

https://www.corning.com/microsites/coc/oem/documents/specialty-fiber/Corning-Specialty-Fiber-Product-Information-Sheets-111913.pdf